# Pause thread on button click resume on button click

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

i've a loop which gets data from some Websites and it takes about an hour for that loop to get the data and populate it in a database, this loop is in a thread and i want to add a button that pauses the thread until the button is clicked again and it resumes where it stopped.
how can i do this in a safe way?

Comment: See if this MSDN [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/d0a05141-6cce-4d2e-bf81-32ab0fee4af7) helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub PauseThreadButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PauseThreadButton.Click
    'REM: Next line puts your thread in a suspended state
    TheThread.Suspend()
End Sub
```

To resume:

```
Public Sub ResumeThreadButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ResumeThreadButton.Click
    'REM: Next line resumes your thread
    TheThread.Resume()
End Sub
```

Comment: ThreadState is a readonly property. It gets the state of the current thread; you CANNOT set the state of the thread using this property. See [Thread.ThreadState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.threadstate.aspx#Y0)

Comment: @RandyDodson: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstate(v=vs.110)

Comment: My apologies. I have corrected the code above (I was thinking of an If...Then statement.). The code above does change the Thread.ThreadState, just not directly.

Comment: Yes. It waits until the thread is in a safe place before suspending. If you want to abort the thread, replace `Suspend` with `Abort`.

Comment: This API is now obsolete. Do not use the Suspend and Resume methods to synchronize the activities of threads. You have no way of knowing what code a thread is executing when you suspend it. If you suspend a thread while it holds locks during a security permission evaluation, other threads in the AppDomain might be blocked. If you suspend a thread while it is executing a class constructor, other threads in the AppDomain that attempt to use that class are blocked. Deadlocks can occur very easily. [Thread.Suspend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx)

Comment: @RandyDodson He's not looking to sync the threads, he's simply trying to pause and resume them.

Comment: I know; my example does just that. Try following the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.suspend.aspx) link and reading for yourself the specifications and ramifications of using Suspend and Resume, which are obsolete. And try not to get hung up on the word 'synchronize'.

Comment: Also, your earlier comment _‘Yes. It waits until the thread is in a safe place before suspending'_ is simply not true. Suspend and Resume do not wait until the thread is in a safe place that is precisely the problem with using them. Try doing more research before answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Windows Console application; it uses a Boolean flag to indicate whether the thread should process or not.  I hope this points you in the right direction.

```
Module Module1

    Private _ThreadControl_Run As Boolean = False

    Sub Main()
        Dim thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadWorker)
        thread.IsBackground = True
        thread.Start()

        _ThreadControl_Run = True
        Console.WriteLine("Main() _ThreadControl_Run = " & _ThreadControl_Run.ToString())
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        _ThreadControl_Run = False
        Console.WriteLine("Main() _ThreadControl_Run = " & _ThreadControl_Run.ToString())
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        _ThreadControl_Run = True
        Console.WriteLine("Main() _ThreadControl_Run = " & _ThreadControl_Run.ToString())
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        _ThreadControl_Run = False
        Console.WriteLine("Main() _ThreadControl_Run = " & _ThreadControl_Run.ToString())
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThreadWorker()
        Do While True
            If (_ThreadControl_Run) Then
                Console.WriteLine("     ThreadWorker()")
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

End Module
```